# Android studio (0,0) is top right in device

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface, padding

After trying to position views programmatically, I noticed the views in my device (as well as other devices with this app) maps (0,0) to top **right** corner instead of left.

In a blank project (0,0) is the top left, so I included simplified version of game_screen.xml to show the problem (including gameLayout caused the problem in my real app), but even after I removed it the problem remains.

API 25

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activityMain.java:

```
package com.benmassarano.mirroredscreendemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout lay = findViewById(R.id.lay);
        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
        positionView(lay, text, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }

    private void positionView(RelativeLayout parent, View view, int widthSetting,
                              int heightSetting) {
        parent.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthSetting,
                                                                                     heightSetting);
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

game_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30s"
            android:textSize="28sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

emulator screenshot:

[image: emulator]

personal device screenshot:

[image: device]

Comment: Have you adjusted any developer options in Settings, such as the force-RTL setting?

Comment: I don't think so (specifically force-RTL is false), anyway it does that in non-developers' devices too

Comment: Your problem extends beyond that one view. Your app bar has its text right-flush, rather than left-flush. So, whatever, your problem is, it lies outside the code in your question. That's why I suggested the developer options setting for RTL.

Comment: Is there more data that may help?

Comment: What about your device language. It is clear from your screenshot that RTL layout is on.

Comment: And even the top bar icons, it's your physical device configuration that you need to change.

Comment: @AnantaRaha hebrew (which is RTL)

Comment: @javdromero so I need to design my apps the opposite way? That odd

Comment: This is the reason I think, if possible, change your language to English or any non-RTL language from system settings and that's it.

Comment: Remember that a lot of app configurations are inherited from the device itself if you don't tell otherwise. That' why on the emulator shows the app left aligned.

Comment: You can of course force it not to support RTL; in your manifest.xml, put `android:supportsRtl="false"`.

Comment: @AnantaRaha It was the RTL thing. Please write that as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your provided screenshot, it is clear that your device configuration is set to RTL(Right to Left) layout.

If you want your app to follow layout direction set by the device, then make sure to put `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your manifest.xml: [details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#supportsrtl)

```
<application android:supportsRtl="true">
    ...
</application>
```

But if you want your app not to support RTL (or device layout direction), put `android:supportsRtl="false"` in your manifest.xml; or just remove this attribute since it is false by default.